# Kibana ES Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im getting the following error of type **illegal_argument_exception**: 
 `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [time] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.` 
I tried doing a

```
 PUT my_index/_mapping
{ 
  "properties": { 
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

As suggested by most documentations and people that had this similar issue, but since time is a date with mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
```

}

 Then another error comes up when trying to fix so (if i switch to 'text' type, else cant set fielddata to true). Any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT: this is the request that Kibana is performing -

```
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "time": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "fixed_interval": "30s",
        "time_zone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "time",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2020-07-27T16:19:30.271Z",
              "lte": "2020-07-27T16:34:30.271Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to perform any sort of search query or aggregation on ```time``` field ? Can u provide any sample data or  can u please tell what sort of query you are performing on the field ?

Comment: edited main post and added the request Kibana is performing

Comment: you definitely don't want to convert your date fields to a text field as kibana will then be unable to do any date-related things (filter, aggs, etc). So if you start from scratch with your time field mapped as date, you get that error?

Comment: Exactly ! It was always on date type and now im getting the error